# Using many markers with leaflet in combination with shiny server

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny-server

I developed a Shiny-app where I make use of the leaflet package to plot a large nr of point (~25.000) on a geographical background. When I start the app from R-studio it all works very well. 
On the same server I have a shiny-server running. I deployd several apps on this server without any problems. I deployd the app on the shiny-server to make it available for end-users.

**The issue**
 On *shiny-server* it looks like the app has a problems handling the number of markers (~25.000). The app 'hangs', I can't do anything, but restart the app. With a smaller number of points (<10.000) there is no problem.
I couldn't find this problem anywhere else.

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to solve it?

Here is my code I used to test the problem

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

     # Deel Interactive Map 
     plot_data <- reactive({
          columns <- c("lng",
                       "lat",
                       "perc_gtv");
          dt_installaties[1:input$nr_points,
                          columns,
                          with=FALSE];

     })

     output$map_branche <- renderLeaflet({
          leaflet() %>% 
               setView(lng = 5.5, 
                       lat = 52.5, 
                       zoom = 8) %>%
               addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.HOT") 

     })
     # Observer that changes the markers as the nr of points is 
     # being changed
     observe({
          pal <- colorBin(palette = c("red","green"),
                          domain = c(0,200),
                          bins = 7)
          leafletProxy("map_branche",
                       data = plot_data()) %>%
               clearMarkers() %>%
               addCircleMarkers(
                    lng = ~lng, 
                    lat = ~lat,
                    color = ~pal(perc_gtv),
                    fillOpacity = 0.9) 


     })

})



shinyUI(
     fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
               numericInput(
                    "nr_points",
                    label = h4("Points to plot"),
                    value = 5000,
                    min = 1,
                    max = nrow(dt_installaties)

               )
          ),
          mainPanel(
               leafletOutput("map_branche")
          )
     )

)
```

**My configuration**

- platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
- R: 3.2.2 R-studio: 0.98.1103
- Leaflet: 1.0.0
- Shiny: 0.12.2
- Shiny-server:  public/free version

Comment: 25,000 markers it's a lot so it might be really slow. look into clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions() or library mapview....

Comment: @MLavoie Not the ideal sollution but it is an option. Because I use color for the value of the variable: do you know how to set the color of the cluster to for example the mean of the variable?

Comment: you set the color as usual...and you will see it's much faster...and another alternative is to add your points by layers (or by group) and use show/hide layers.

Comment: I tried passing the color and radius of the clustericons as options, but this doens't work. Going into the leaflet packages [link](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) it seems you have to define it as a new function. Can't this be done simpler?

Comment: maybe you could take a look at the mapview package. It's built on leaflet but it is supposed to be faster

Comment: Nice. I will have look. But since it is a wrapper of leaflet, how can it be faster?

Comment: have a look at [mapdeck](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck) and [leaflet glify](https://github.com/tim-salabim/leaflet.glify) - both of which can handle millions of points.