# Shiny turns grey when running on server - leaflet takes long to build up

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I run a shiny app on our local server to map different geodata with leaflet.
Some datasets I want to map are available as WMS and are loaded with

```
%>% addWMSTiles()
```

Other data are stored as SpatialPolygonDataFrame (SPDF) as .rda files locally and are plotted with

```
%>% addPolygons()
```

when the app is executed.

When running the app on my local laptop everything works fine - it takes rd. 15-20sec to build up the app, because I plot 18 different WMS and 5 different SPDF.

However, problems arise when I run the app on our server. After some time (during building up) the app suddenly turns grey.

I found out that the slow build up of the app is because of the local SPDF files. However, the local SPDF files have a size of max 1.5 MB.

I wonder if there is a better solution to plot polygons. Is there a recommended format for geo-polygons in shiny / leaflet?

Comment: What server? Is this the shiny hosting service? If so have you looked at the logs?

Comment: It is our company`s own server. Accessible only through our intranet.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Running local, it works fine, running it on shiny-server, it greys out. See [Using many markers with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607908/using-many-markers-with-leaflet-in-combination-with-shiny-server) for my description. Apperantly there is a limit on the nr of polygons that leaflet can handle which is different when using shiny-server. There appears to be no real solution to this execept plotting less polygons. For example by using markerclusters.